# MonoRail - Select parent category from one dropdown, show child category dropdown

Tags: castle-monorail

I'm new to MonoRail and am trying to figure out how to have it so that I can select a parent category in a dropdown then have it show a second dropdown with the categories that are children of the parent.

If I were using what I'm used to, ASP.NET MVC, I would have a javascript function that would be called onchange of the first dropdown and would make an ajax call to a controller method (passing in the selected parent category id) that would grab all child categories of that parent category and return them in JSON. Then in the callback javascript function I would eval the JSON and populate the second dropdown with the child categories.

How would I do this using MonoRail/jQuery? Here's the code I have so far:

```
$FormHelper.Select("business.category.id", $categories, "%{value='id', text='name', firstoption='Select a Category'}")

$FormHelper.Select("business.category.id", $childCategories, "%{value='id', text='name', firstoption='Select a Sub-Category'}")
```

Then in BusinessController.cs:

```
private void AddDataToModels()
        {
            PropertyBag["categories"] = CategoryRepository.GetParentCategories();
            PropertyBag["childCategories"] = CategoryRepository.GetChildCategories(1);
}
```

Thanks for any input on how to approach this!

Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this one helps:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/10/08/Cascading-Drop-Downs-in-MonoRail.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I actually saw that article after I posted but he's using a .ashx file for doing the server-side call from ajax. How would I call a controller action from ajax? It gives me "MonoRail could not resolve a view engine instance for the template..."

Comment: Here's a quick post I did a while ago on using ajax from Monorail.  It uses prototype, but the same concept will work for jQuery too:

http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2008/09/15/easy-ajax-with-monorail.aspx

Comment: This method wasn't good for my situation since it's basically returning a whole view, reminds me too much of update panels from ASP.NET. I was looking for a way to return JSON back and deal with that rather than an entire view. However, I'm giving you the answer since you got me on the right track and were the only one to respond, thanks for your help!!

Comment: Thanks Justin.  Another approach some people have used is to always return json and then use a javascript templating library to generate the HTML on the client (again, I've heard of this but haven't tried it).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for others who are looking to call controller actions from jQuery and return JSON...

Controller Method:

```
[return: JSONReturnBinder(Properties = "Id,Name")]
        public BusinessType[] GetChildBusinessTypes(int parentId)
        {
            var businessTypes = BusinessTypeRepository.GetChildBusinessTypes(parentId);
            return businessTypes;
        }
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#business_parentbusinesstype_id').change(function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "$UrlHelper.For("%{action='$business.site.id/GetChildBusinessTypes'}")",
                data: { parentId: $('#business_parentbusinesstype_id').val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                success: fillChildBusinessTypes,
                error: ajaxError
            });
        });
    });

    function fillChildBusinessTypes(json) {
        //get business types.
        var businessTypes = eval(json);
        //bind business types to dropdown.
        $("#business_businesstype_id").get(0).options.length = 0;
        $("#business_businesstype_id").get(0).options[0] = new Option("Select a Business Type", "0");
        jQuery.each(businessTypes, function(index, item) {
            $('#business_businesstype_id').get(0).options[$("#business_businesstype_id").get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Name, item.Id);
        });
        //show child dropdown.
        Show($('#spnChildBusinessTypes'));
    }
```